# Criteria Builder String based - Expression quot as double - JPA

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, java-ee-6, criteria-api

New to CB, I'm trying to use it instead of native queries. The reason is I'll need different grouping by situations.
Here's what I'm need to reproduce:

```
(1 - sum( field_1 [integer])::real / sum ( field_2 [integer])::real  ) * 100
```

Here's the code which suppose to do that:

```
Expression<Double> filed1Sum = cb.sumAsDouble(report.<Float>get("field1"));
Expression<Double> filed2Sum = cb.sumAsDouble(report.<Float>get("field2"));
Expression<Double> expected = cb.toDouble(cb.<Float>quot(filed1Sum, filed2Sum));
```

The problem is:  the expected value is coming as Long!!! As the field1 is aways less than field2 I've got 0 (zero). I'm wondering get 0.888 something like that.

Comment: What does it mean the _string based_ you have put in the title? Are `field1` and `field2` numeric java fields or not?

Comment: 1 -String based get("String") as opposed to Metamodel based get.(_Class).

Comment: 2 - Of course not. They're INTEGER database fields not Java

Comment: 1 - Ok. 2 - Ok they are integers in the db. But what type do they have in the java Entity class?

Comment: They're Integer as well.  Notice that filed1Sum and filed2Sum are coming as Double.  The result of quot(filed1Sum, filed2Sum) returns a Long type.
(I'm testing using CriteriaQuery<Tuple> and debugging the results as alias.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved by multiplying the dividend by 1.0D:

```
Expression<Number> expected = cb.quot(cb.prod(filed1Sum,cb.literal(1.0D)), filed2Sum);
```

That generates the query:

```
(sum(field1) * 1.0) / sum(field2)
```

Which returns a floating point correctly. 
No explicit conversions were required.

Thank you for the efforts to help me